# Output menu title

Tags: menus, title

Is it possible to output the title of wp_nav_menu somehow? The closest I could find was http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_a_Word_at_the_Beginning_of_the_Menu. For the sake of the client and the inclusion of Polylang, I figured it would be nice to enable the user to edit these titles directly under the menu settings in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This outputs the title of a menu using `wp_get_nav_menu_object` (and prepends to the Content).

```
function pg_show_nav_menu_title ( $content ) {

    // ID of the menu you want
    $nav_menu_id = 14;

    //Get menu into an object
    $nav_menu_object = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $nav_menu_id );

    //Get the name (title)
    $nav_menu_title = $nav_menu_object->name;

    //String to return as Content
    $content = 'Nav menu title: ' . $nav_menu_title . '<br>' . $content;

    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content' , 'pg_show_nav_menu_title' );
```

Note: You can get the id of any menu in Dashboard > Appearance > Menus. Right-click on the Select menu and show source. The numbers in the options are the IDs. In the example above, I grabbed '14' from:

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
    <option value="14">Primary</option>
    <option value="237">Top (Secondary Navigation Menu)</option>
</select>
```